# Color points based on values in OpenLayers 6

Tags: style, features, openlayers

I'm trying to color points based on a value called 'ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE', in a GeoJSON dataset but I can't get it to work. Here is what I have set up so far:

Create the GeoJSON data source:

```
    const sourcePoints = new VectorSource({
      url: './data/dataset1_fixed.json',
      format: new GeoJSON()
    });
```

Next, I have a function that bins features based on the value of 'ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE' for each feature:

```
    
      if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') >= 0 && 'ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE' <= 100) {
        fillcolor = '#2b83ba';
      } else if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') > 100 && ('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') <= 200) {
        fillcolor = '#91cba9';
      } else if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') > 200 && ('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') <= 300) {
        fillcolor = '#def2b4';
      } else if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') > 300 && ('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') <= 400) {
        fillcolor = '#ffdf9a';
      } else if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') > 400 && ('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') <= 500) {
        fillcolor = '#f69053';
      } else if(feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE') > 500) {
        fillcolor = '#d7191c';
      }
    
      return [new CircleStyle({
        image: new Circle({
          fill: new Fill({color: fillcolor}),
          stroke: new Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1}),
          radius: 5
        }),
      })];
    };
```

Last, I set up the Map() and View(), and pass in the customStyleFunction() for style.

```
  new Map({
    target: 'map-container',
    layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),

    new VectorLayer({
      source: sourcePoints,
      style: customStyleFunction
      })],
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([-70, 35]),
    zoom: 10
  })
});
```

I get an error 'fillcolor is not defined'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem with your style function is that when none of conditions for styling is fulfilled, `fillcolor` variable stays undefined. What's missing is simple `else` condition at the end to assign value to `fillcolor` variable when all other conditions fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a simple JavaScript error, you should declare `fillcolor` before attempting to assign as value to it.  Also the comparisons after the `&&` will always be false as you have omitted `feature.get`.  Instead of repeating `feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE')` it would be better to set a value:

```
  const value = feature.get('ML_ABSOLUTE_VALUE');
  let fillcolor;
  if(value >= 0 && value <= 100) {
    fillcolor = '#2b83ba';
  } else if(value > 100 && value <= 200) {
    fillcolor = '#91cba9';
  } else if(value > 200 && value <= 300) {
    fillcolor = '#def2b4';
  } else if(value > 300 && value <= 400) {
    fillcolor = '#ffdf9a';
  } else if(value > 400 && value <= 500) {
    fillcolor = '#f69053';
  } else if(value > 500){
    fillcolor = '#d7191c';
  }
```

If none of the conditions applied `color` will be `undefined` (i.e. OpenLayers default).

Comment: Thanks @Mike! I noticed my typo there with the lack of 'feature.get()'. I can't seem to get the feature.get() function to work at all, even after fixing that typo. My data source is a GeoJSON file--would that matter?